# How do you modify a file and commit it in a pre-push hook, and the current push includes the commit?

Tags: git, web-frontend

I'm currently working on a front-end project that uses husky to add git hooks

I need to change something in package.json before each code push, and then I need to make the current push include this automated change.

I now use Husky to add the pre-push hook, and then do the following from the hook:

- Modify the package.json file
- Run git add package.json
- Run git commit -m "modify something"
- Execute git push --no-verify

The above step can indeed achieve my purpose, but it will remind me every time I push, one push has been rejected, which is very bad, how can I solve this problem? My ultimate goal is still to modify the file before pushing and make sure that the current push contains the changes and is not limited to my current method.

Answer (score 2):

You are abusing the git-push hook. As you can read in the documentation [githooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_push):

> This hook is called by [git-push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) and can be used to prevent a push from taking place. [...]

Your attempt to modify the history while it is being pushed is outside the scope of the hook.

If you have to make a change to the history before it is pushed, then put this procedure in a script that makes the necessary changes to the history, and *then* calls `git push` as the last step.

Use the pre-push hook only for the purpose that is documented. This one is in particular a hook that treats the repository as read-only.

Comment: I don't really care about the hook design, I want to implement the business logic that I need to change the project version number and write the push time somewhere in the project before the project code pushes, the problem is also raised in the hope of getting a better solution to the business logic, not to tame the hooks of git

Comment: As I said, the hook is not the right place to implement this business logic.